# Use of “that” in sentence

Tags: grammar

Can the “ that”  be used with all verbs as is the case with sentence below. I mean Is the structure in sentence below genaral grammar rule ?

> It affected my life that she left me without saying goodbye.

Answer (score 1):

"That" has many uses, and one of them, as in your case here, is functioning as conjunction. Which means it links two independent sentences together in one complete meaningful sentence; thus it can show how the two joined parts are related.

Similar examples where "that" is used as a conjunction:

> - His way of acting nicely with everyone is **so** admirable **that** no one would ever think of hurting him.
> - They left the house in **such** a hurry **that** they forgot to turn the lights off.

Note that "that" takes "so" with adjectives/adverbs and "such" with nouns but nothing with verbs as in your example. The reason for that is because *one thing causes the other*.

[Here](https://www.englishgrammar.org/uses-of-that/) you can find all the possible uses of "that".

Comment: Your second example sentence is ungrammatical. It needs to be something like *in **such** a hurry*.

Comment: Very true; I have corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

> *It affected my life* [*that she left me without saying goodbye*].

Declarative content clauses *(that*-clauses) functioning as adjuncts seem fine with a few verbs that allow a resultative or purposive meaning. They are quite rare though, since such clauses normally function as complement.

The adjunct here has a resultative meaning; compare: "She left me ... with the result that it affected my life."